# GetStaticPaths Error:Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error when as I map the response from my get staticpath. I have tried to destructure the response object but to no avail. As a result when i click on a single item, i get this error message. I have added the link to the codesandbox.

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/';

export async function fetchMeal(id) {
 const res = await axios.get(`/lookup.php?i=${id}`);
 const meal = await res.data.meals[0];

 return meal;
}

export async function fetchMeals() {
 const res = await axios.get('/search.php?s=');
 const meal = await res.data.meals;

 return meal;
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetchMeals()
  const paths = res.map((meal) => ({
    params: { id: meal.idMeal },
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const recipe = await fetchMeal(params.id)

  return {
    props: {
      recipe,
    },
  }
}
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/peteregbujie/nextjs-recipe-app)

How can I get the right array instead of the object?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your `<Navbar/>` component.

You defined is as

```js
function Navbar(title = "Recipe Finder") {
 return (
     <div className={styles.head}>
     ...
     <title>{title}</title>
     ....
     </div>
 )
```

Note the `title` variable that you're passing as a parameter to the function.

The problem is that this function is actually a React component. When React is calling your component it passes `props` to the function. Although you have it as `Navbar(title = "Recipe Finder")`, during the runtime React will call it as `Navbar(props)`. It will override your `title` variable with `prop` object, which I believe in this case is just empty object `{}`. Hence you're getting the error, because react cannot render the `title` (i.e. it effectively becomes `<title>{{}}</title>`)

To fix the problem you can change it to

```js
function Navbar() {
 const title = "Recipe Finder";
```

Comment: Wow! It worked. So, I changed the function to an arrow function and wrapped the parameter in a curly braces. 

const Navbar =({title = "Recipe Finder"})=> { 
 ....
     <title>{title}</title>

Thank you so much.